# What happens to uncollected pins after battles?

Tags: neo-the-world-ends-with-you

In *NEO: TWEWY*, if a defeated enemy drops a pin during battle and I avoid picking it up, what happens to that pin? Will the pin disappear if I don’t collect it? Or are pins auto-collected when the battle finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncollected pins will be picked up automatically either after 30 seconds of being left alone, or when you complete the battle.